# Call method of current "level" of class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

**Is it possible to call the current classes methods in a class inheritance?**

Lets say we have a class A and a Class B which inherits from A. Now both have an "initialize" method, meaning it gets overriden in B. Now i **can not** use "base.initialize" to call A's "initialize" from there. Instead im trying to call it from the lower classes constructor (so A's constructor), which gets called for all inherited classes.

So now i want to **call A's "initialize" on A's constructor**. But when i try that, the overriding constructor of B gets called.

So is there something to tell VS (or c#) that i'm explicitly calling the methods of the class im currently in (this.method() didn't work)?

Comment: Are you sure it is overriden? And seriously, what are you trying to accomplish? There is probably a more straightforward way to achieve your goal.

Comment: It seems like you shouldn't be overriding the initialize method.

Comment: Methods in C# are not virtual by default - you have to use a `virtual` keyword to mark them as such and then use an `override` keyword on methods in child classes. If you do that, you absolutely **can** use `base.Initialize()` from the `B` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mark a method `Initialize` as virtual, that means that a derived class is free to override that method, potentially not calling `base.Initialize` in the process. If it is not okay if that scenario occurs, then don't mark the method as virtual.

In your case, it sounds like you just need two private `Initialize` methods in each class:

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you might want to have a look at the [Template Method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). You could design your classes like this:

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        // Initialize the base class A.

        // Then call DerivedInitialize. If this is actually a derived object,
        // DerivedInitialize will initialize the derived instance. Otherwise,
        // it won't do anything.
        DerivedInitialize();
    }

    protected virtual void DerivedInitialize()
    {
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void DerivedInitialize()
    {
        // Initialize B-specific stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. Especially the second possibility seems to fit very well.

Answer (score 0):

Put contents of your `A.initialize()` to a new private nonvirtual method. Call this new method from `A`'s constructor and `A.initialize()`.